# Prove optimality of assignment problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, solution-verification

I'm trying to write a proof to prove that given two arrays of numbers both of size $n$, sorting them by increasing order and pairing them by index creates the matching with least cost, where cost of $(a,b)$ is $|a-b|$. In other words, I sort each array independently to get $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ and $(b_1,b_2,...,b_n)$ where $a_i \leq a_j$ and $b_i\leq b_j$ when $i<j$, then pair them by index to get $(a_1,b_1)$, $(a_2,b_2)$,...,$(a_n,b_n)$.

I think a way to do this is to prove that if I take any two pairs $(a_i,b_i)$ and $(a_j,b_j)$ from the sorted arrays and swap them, i.e., resulting in $(a_i,b_j)$ and $(a_j,b_i)$, then:

$$|a_i-b_i|+|a_j-b_j| \leq |a_i-b_j|+|a_j-b_i|$$

But I'm not sure how to do the math to prove this statement. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hint: triangle inequality.

Comment: @RobPratt : Can you elaborate a little? I'm stuck on how exactly to apply it here.

Comment: Maybe a better hint is that you can consider $4!/2^2=6$ cases. And, without loss of generality, $a_i\le b_i$, so you can reduce even further to only 3 cases.

Comment: @RobPratt: That still makes no sense to me. What are the cases?

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with these kinds of proofs.

Comment: One case is $a_i\le a_j\le b_i\le b_j$.

Comment: @RobPratt : Ah, I see now. Is it also fair to say that without loss of generality I can assume all $a,b \ge 0$?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think that shortens the argument.

Comment: @RobPratt : You're right; it doesn't. I posted an answer to my question based on your hints that I think is correct. Please let me know if you see any mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer looks good to me (+1).  Here's an alternative presentation that explicitly shows the double-counted intervals in cases 2 and 3.

Case 1 ($a_i \leq a_j \leq b_i \leq b_j$):
\begin{align}
|a_i-b_i| + |a_j-b_j| &= (b_i-a_i)+(b_j-a_j)\\
&= (b_j-a_i)+(b_i-a_j)\\
&= |a_i-b_j|+|a_j-b_i|
\end{align}

Case 2 ($a_i \leq b_i \leq a_j \leq b_j$):
\begin{align}
|a_i-b_i| + |a_j-b_j| &= (b_i-a_i)+(b_j-a_j) \\
&\le (b_i-a_i)+(b_j-a_j) + 2(a_j-b_i)\\
&= (b_j-a_i)+(a_j-b_i) \\
&= |a_i-b_j|+|a_j-b_i|
\end{align}

Case 3 ($a_i \leq b_i \leq b_j \leq a_j$):
\begin{align}
|a_i-b_i| + |a_j-b_j| &= (b_i-a_i)+(a_j-b_j) \\
&\le (b_i-a_i)+(a_j-b_j) + 2(b_j-b_i)\\
&= (b_j-a_i)+(a_j-b_i) \\
&= |a_i-b_j|+|a_j-b_i|
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Based on Rob Pratt's hints, I have written the following solution:

$$|a_i-b_i| + |a_j-b_j| \leq |a_i-b_j|+|a_j-b_i| \;\;\;\;(1)$$

Knowing that $a_i\leq a_j$ and $b_i \leq b_j$, there are $4!/2^{2} = 6$ possible cases for the order of the four numbers. However, we can assume, without loss of generality, that $a_i \leq b_i$ and consider the three remaining cases.

3 Cases:
$$1) \;a_i \leq a_j \leq b_i \leq b_j$$
$$2) \;a_i \leq b_i \leq a_j \leq b_j$$
$$3) \;a_i \leq b_i \leq b_j \leq a_j$$

Consider case 1: Due to the ordering, we can rewrite inequality (1) without absolute values as such:

$$-(a_i-b_i)+-(a_j-b_j) \leq -(a_i-b_j)+-(a_j-b_i)$$

$$-a_i+b_i-a_j+b_j \leq -a_i+b_j-a_j+b_i$$

$$0 \leq 0$$

which is true, so case 1 satisfies the inequality.

Consider case 2: Due to the ordering, we can rewrite inequality (1) without absolute values as such:

$$-(a_i-b_i)+-(a_j-b_j) \leq -(a_i-b_j)+(a_j-b_i)$$

$$-a_i+b_i-a_j+b_j \leq -a_i+b_j+a_j-b_i$$

$$b_i-a_j \leq a_j-b_i$$

which is true because $b_i\leq a_j$. So, case 2 satisfies the inequality.

Consider case 3: Due to the ordering, we can rewrite inequality (1) without absolute values as such:

$$-(a_i-b_i)+a_j-b_j \leq -(a_i-b_j)+a_j-b_i$$

$$-a_i+b_i+a_j-b_j \leq -a_i+b_j+a_j-b_i$$

$$b_i-b_j \leq -b_i+b_j$$

$$2b_i \leq 2b_j$$

$$b_i\leq b_j$$

Which is true, so case 3 satisfies the inequality.

Hence, because all possible cases satisfy the inequality, the inequality holds.

Comment: Those are the right three cases, but I have a few suggestions: 1. Change $r$ to $a$ to match the question. 2. Argue the cases in the same order you list them. 3. Use the ordering to remove the absolute values; doing so will simplify the proof.

Comment: Updated it according to your suggestions.